# How to instantiate a Graph Chart?

Tags: vba, graph, ms-word

I am currently trying to create a chart, e.g. a piechart through word vba.

The problem is that the machine(s) where this word vba will be run do not have excel available, only word and ms graph.

I have tried to create a chart with ms graph, but I am not able to make it work.

As from the code below, I can create charts with inlineshapes and chart and I get a nice bar chart presented in the word window.

I am not able to instantiate the chart element for Ms Graph. I found a french guide that shows how it should be done, but I am not able to get the "me.graphique1"-part to make sense.

## Inlineshapes

```
Dim vlChart As Chart

Set vlChart = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddChart2.Chart
```

## Graph

```
Dim vlChart As Graph.Chart

Set vlChart = Me.Graphique1.Object.Application.Chart
```

I would expect to be able to create a graph object, but I don't know what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No guarantees that this will still work, since MS Graph has long been deprecated. The following code sample demonstrates how to insert an MS Graph object and access its data sheet.

This code requires a reference to the MS Graph object library in VBA Tools/References. I highly recommend you use it, at least while writing the code so that you have Intellisense.

```
Dim grph as Graph.Chart
Dim grphData as Graph.DataSheet
Dim grphApp as Graph.Application
Dim doc as Word.Document
Dim oleF as Word.OLEFormat
Dim rng as Word.Range

Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set rng = doc.Content
Set oleF = doc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(ClassType:="MSGraph.Chart.8", Range:=rng).OLEFormat
oleF.DoVerb
Set grphChart = oleF.Object
Set grphApp = grphChart.Application
Set grphData = grphApp.DataSheet
grphData.Cells.Clear
'Now start entering the data and formatting the chart
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Even though MS Graph is very old it is what I need to use in my current situation, excel is not available, so it limits our options to create graphs.